# Minimum sum number pairing

Tags: optimization, algorithms

> Given $n$ real numbers (being $n$ even) pair them so if we sum up the components of every pair and take the maximum no other possible pairing produce such a lower maximum.

I think the optimal pairing is obtained by sorting the original set and pair the first element with the last and so on. But I get stuck trying to prove it.

I try to suppose that there is another optimal pairing and try to modify it without losing optimility until both pairings become equal. Any idea?

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you describe what approaches you've tried? I was thinking about contradiction, but doesn't pan out, at least not directly, in a number of cases.

Comment: This problem was given to me in the context of greedy algorithms design. An usual technique to prove the correctness of the algorithm is to suppose we have the optimal answer to the problem. Then, examining differences between the optimal answer and the "greedy" answer, try to transform the optimal answer so it gets more similar to the greedy one without losing its optimality.

Comment: I ask this as well in CSSE, the answer is here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/80865/76479